# Fitting parameters given an inverse function. (Orosi, 2015)

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, risk-neutral-measure, numerical-methods

In trying to replicate Orosi's (2015) 5-parameter implied volatility model, but I can't wrap my head around the parameter fitting procedure Orosi proposes. My main goal is to calibrate the model to my set of observed call prices, so that I can derive the Risk-neutral-density function.

Consider that I have empirical observations of call prices, $c$ for a range of exercise prices, $x$, for a given time and maturity. I then have to minimise the squared errors:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(c(x_i)-c_i)^2$

Where $c(x_i)$ has to be numerically determined from the equation:

$x_i=1-c(x_i)+G\frac{(1-c(x_i))^\beta}{c(x_i)^\alpha}*(Ac(x_i)+1)^\gamma$

With the following constraints:

$G>0,\alpha>0,\beta>2,\gamma>1,0>A>-1$

Now I am pretty comfortable with minimising the objective function in Python using e.g. scipy's fmin function etc. However, as noted by the author, as $c(x)$ is provided in an **inverted** manner "$c(x)$ has to be numerically derived using a golden section search or something similar". I have no idea how to go about this and to implement it in a "usual" non-linear least squares minimisation method?

If anyone could point me in the right direction or provide Python or pseudo-code so I can figure it out myself it would be highly appreciated

Comment: I'm always skeptical when papers leave things vague like this. It's also a model that is very different from anything i've seen before, so if you get it working i'd be curious to see what it's like. Though i'm dubious given that it's a paper from 2019, and the data they use to fit to has an average bid/offer spread of almost 10%, and the average error of the fit is 1.85%. An average error of 1.85% is, IMO, unusable. Let me know if you get it working and how well it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some form of optimization technique twice. Once to solve for $c(x_i)$ and another one to minimize the MSE. I have added below a quick hack of the problem where minimize_scalar is used to solve for $c(x_i)$ and the brute force algorithm is used to solve for the parameters that minimize the MSE. There are definitely better optimizations to be used, but this should provide the structure you are looking for.

Words of caution: as mentioned in the comments I am skeptical if this is at all usable in practice. Also a 5 variable global minimization problem is very difficult to solve and I suspect the solutions will be unreliable and unusable in practice.

Good luck!

```
from scipy import optimize

PRECISION = 1e-3

def error_c(c, params, x):
    error = abs(1-c+params[0]*((1-c)**params[2]/(c**params[1]))*(params[4]*c+1)**params[3]-x)
    return error

def get_c(x, params):
    c = optimize.minimize_scalar(error_c,
                                 bounds=(PRECISION, 1/PRECISION),
                                 method='bounded',
                                 args=(params, x),
                                 tol=PRECISION)
    return c.x

def mse(params, x, c):
    mse = 0
    for x_i, c_i in zip(x, c):
        mse += (get_c(x_i, params)-c_i)**2
    return(mse)

x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
c = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]

bounds = ((PRECISION, 1/PRECISION),
          (PRECISION, 1/PRECISION),
          (2+PRECISION, 1/PRECISION),
          (1+PRECISION, 1/PRECISION),
          (-1+PRECISION, -PRECISION))

result = optimize.brute(mse, ranges=bounds, args=(x, c), Ns=10)
print(result)
```